# handling state with react context and react hook form

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context, react-hook-form

I have a form that has an add/edit mode. In edit mode, my text area input takes the post.content as the default value.
When I edit the post once, it's working, the post is edited but When I edit the post a second time, the default value of the text area is the old state post.content and not the edited one.
Do you know why the value of the text area not taking the last post state? If I refresh before two edits there is no problem

PostsContext.tsx

```
const reducer = (state: PostsState, action: PostsAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_POSTS':
      return { posts: action.payload }
    case 'ADD_POST':
      return { posts: [action.payload, ...state.posts] }
    case 'UPDATE_POST':
      return {
        posts: state.posts.map((post) => {
          if (post.id === action.payload.id) {
            return action.payload
          }
          return post
        }),
      }
    case 'DELETE_POST':
      return {
        posts: state.posts.filter((post) => post.id !== action.payload.id),
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Posts.tsx

```
    const Posts = ({ post }: Props) => {
      const { dispatch } = usePostsContext()
 const { dispatch } = usePostsContext()
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    watch,
    reset,
    formState: { isSubmitting, errors },
  } = useForm<FormInput>({
    defaultValues: {
      content: post?.content || '',
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(postSchema),
  })
    
      const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormInput> = async (data) => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('content', data.content)
        data.thumbnailFile && formData.append('thumbnailFile', data.thumbnailFile[0])
        const response = await fetch(
          `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/api/posts/${post ? post.id : ''}`,
          {
            method: post ? 'PATCH' : 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: formData,
          }
        )
        const json = await response.json()
        if (response.ok) {
          dispatch({ type: post ? 'UPDATE_POST' : 'ADD_POST', payload: json })
          reset()
          post && setUpdateMode(false)
        }
      }
    
      return (
    
            <Avatar />
    
            {!updateMode && (
              <div className="dropdown dropdown-end">
                <label tabIndex={0} className="btn btn-square">
                  ...
                </label>
                <ul
                  tabIndex={0}
                  className="dropdown-content menu p-2 shadow bg-base-100 rounded-box w-52"
                >
                  <li>
                    <span onClick={() => setUpdateMode(true)}>Edit</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <span onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
    
          {updateMode ? (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <div className="flex flex-col">
                <textarea
                  className="w-full h-32 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"
                  placeholder="What's on your mind?"
                  {...register('content', { required: true })}
                />
                  </div>
                )}
    
                <div className="divider"></div>
    
                  {post ? (
                    <div className="flex items-center">
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-outline btn-ghost mr-2"
                        onClick={() => {
                          reset(), setUpdateMode(false)
                        }}
                      >
                        Cancel
                      </button>
                      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-accent" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                        {isSubmitting ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-accent" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                      {isSubmitting ? 'Posting...' : 'Post'}
                    </button>
                  )}
                </div>
            </form>
          ) : (
            post && (
              <Post />
    
            )
      )
    }
    
    export default Posts
```

Comment: I don't know [tag:react-hook-form] but the code where you define the initial value for `"control"` seems to be missing, there should be a `useForm` call somewhere, no? Please create a [example], you can use [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx) to do that, but also include the code in the question.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you don't use [`setValue`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue/) and only update the initial value. (I imagine you are passing the `state` returned from `useReducer` to the `useForm` call, I don't think that is enough, but I never used the library, this is simply a guess.)

Comment: You really need to simplify the code in the question and make sure that it's runable. Otherwise, I can just guess. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: I edited the missing part with `useForm`.  When I remove the default value in `useForm()` and place it in the text area instead, then it's working properly. Thanks for taking time to help me